# Creating a tapered pattern in shader nodes

Tags: node-editor, shaders, procedural

I created this using shader nodes. now i want to taper the bottom instead of straight lines.

which nodes will help me to achieve that?

Please advise,

Thank you,

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depending on the direction of your UV mapping, you might have to switch X and Y in this kind of set-up, which follows your modulo + color-ramp method as far as possible:

[image]

Any other method which makes the *Less-Than* threshold depend on a  dimension orthogonal to the one whose modulo is taken will do the same.

[image]

This tree also makes the period, base, and amplitude of the triangle-wave adjustable.